# Java Gradle Project could not find GradleWorkerMain

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, java-11

After updating to Java 11 from 8, my project's modules build fails with exception. Project is Spring Boot based.

This is what I get when running `./gradlew build`

```
Error: Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
Could not find or load main class worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain
```

and this when I try to run Spring Application

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
    at ee.tk.tkis2.Tkis2MyAppApplication.main(Tkis2MyAppApplication.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

I have reinstalled project, Java, Gradle several times to no avail. deleted `%USER&/.gradle` folder, regenerated Gradle wrapper. Clean-rebuild does nothing. I'm using Intellj IDE, but the problem seems not to be due to my IDE

Does anyone have any idea what the cause might be?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the Gradle *.caches* folder under the user home directory?

Comment: if you mean user/.gradle/caches, then yes, no .cache folder in my user home directory. And by clean I mean delete

Comment: Maybe gradle can't find gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar. If this is the case, you can setup the environment variable. Under System Variables select Path, add an entry for C:\Gradle\gradle-*your_version\bin.

Comment: gradle bin is defined at system environment variables, so that would not be the case

Comment: Could you try stopping the gradle daemon and then relaunch it by gradle build again ?
gradle --stop or ./gradlew --stop 
Based on your setup , the daemon is relaunched when you attempt to build again

Comment: the stop command does stop one gradle daemon, but still the error(s) remain(s)

Comment: How did you update your JDK version? Could you please provide more insights on what you have done exactly? Could you add your whole *build.gradle* file content as well and describe how you are launching the application?

Comment: @NKShukla Your suggestion works for me. I had the same problem after upgrading from TestNG 7.7.1 to 7.8.0.